# Unexpeceted output when i don't await Model.deleteMany()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i am trying to delete all the tasks created by an user when the user deletes itself

```
await req.user.remove();

userSchema.pre('remove',async function(next){
     const user = this;
     TaskModel.deleteMany({owner : user._id});
     next();});
```

but this doesnt delete any tasks created by user.

1. It deletes when i await TaskModel.deleteMany();
   I fail to understand this behavior.
2. It also works perfectly when i add simple callback via then() to TaskModel.deleteMany();

My understanding is that if it doesnt delete when i dont write await then it also should not delete even if i write then callback.

Comment: How do you check if delete was succesful?

Comment: Using studio3t to check db

Comment: That is indeed weird, there should be no difference in the behaviours

Comment: Can you show an example with `then` that works?

Comment: Just simple .then(result=>console.log(result))

Comment: I thought that maybe this `next()` was inside this `then`